# Using nikon lenses on a canon body

Tags: lens-recommendation

Has anybody converted from Nikon to Canon and continued to use their Nikon Lenses with adapters, and how did that workout - as far as focus, aperture, ISO, and fitment.  My wife has many Canon Lenses and I have a D200 so we have 2 times the lenses in most cases with a few Nikon DX (APS-C sensor dedicated) lenses - without considering the full frame scenario and lens compatibility.  Considering switching but losses seem certain if I have to sell all my Nikon lenses, was wondering if there would be a best type lens to keep - Auto Focus and  Aperture.